# mock dictionary at module level

Tags: python, mocking

I try to mock a dictionary at module level:

```
with mock.patch('mymodule.mydict', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock) as mock_dict:
    mock_dict.return_value={'foo': 'bar'}
    ...
```

But it does not work. Inside the with-statement the dictionary is empty.

I read the [docs](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.PropertyMock), but could not find a solution.

Any hints?

Comment: From the docs: *A mock intended to be used as a property, or other descriptor, **on a class**.* A descriptor **requires** a class to work, it cannot work at the global (module) scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-dict) to mock a dictionary:

```
with patch.dict('mymodule.mydict', {'newkey': 'newvalue'}):
    assert mymodule.mydict == {'newkey': 'newvalue'}
```